# JSON POST failed to get the response data

Tags: jquery

I had development one simple web page using html and jquery code that will pass data to my gateway using http post. The response of from server was json object, {"remarks":"SUCCEED"}. However, my web page always failed to get the related response

Below is my web page code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Loading data into a PhoneGap ap2p</title>    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jsonp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="your-tweets"></ul>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8091/gateway/jjh/v1.0/login?userid=ccc&password=pwd',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'userid=wcc',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("Success>>");

    var obj = responseData;
    alert(obj.remarks);

    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
}); 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Can anyone help/advice me on this?

Comment: Is your script running on `http://localhost:8091/`?

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox/Firebug to look at the HTTP responses?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Firebug or Chrome developer tool and check out the console. If there is an error message that reads `Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` then you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can solve this by:

- Moving your web page and JSON source under the same domain.
- Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead.